# Why the dict out of List are separate

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Name = []
Address = []
for a in range(1):
    Name = raw_input ('Enter Name: ')
    Address = raw_input ('Enter Address: ')
    print Name
    print Address
    print [dict(zip(Name, e)) for  e in Address]
    a +=1
```

This is what i am getting

```
Enter Name: Kapil
Enter Address: Soni
Kapil
Soni
[{'K': 'S'}, {'K': 'o'}, {'K': 'n'}, {'K': 'i'}]
```

i want to create as below

```
{'Kapil':'Soni'}
```

what wrong am i doing?

Comment: Why are you not doing `{Name : Address}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
addressbook = {}
for a in range(1):
    name = raw_input ('Enter Name: ')
    address = raw_input ('Enter Adress: ')
    addressbook[name] = address
print addressbook
```

---

```
names = []
addresses = []
for a in range(1):
    name = raw_input ('Enter Name: ')
    address = raw_input ('Enter Adress: ')
    names.append(name)
    addresses.append(address)
print dict(zip(names, addresses))
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using the same name for the list of names and the input variable to hold a single name. Try this:

```
name_address_pairs = []

for a in range(1):
    name = raw_input ('Enter Name: ')
    address = raw_input ('Enter Address: ')
    print name
    print address
    name_address_pairs.append( { name: address } )
```

(As a side note, variable names should begin with lowercase letters by convention.)

Comment: However what he *really* wants is `names_to_addresses = {}` and then to set `names_to_addresses[name] = address` - no point in the dict if you can't use it... (falsetru has posted it I see)

Comment: The single-iteration loop makes it unclear what he actually wants (although I suspect you and falsetru are correct).

Comment: well i just want to test with single loop for test purpose if i am getting correct result . as if i increase the loop on test i have to enter several name and address to check which is quite boring. the ans to problem was very simple !! :( didn't come in my mind though ! i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `Name = []` and then assign `Name = input()` which changes the data type to string.

Also, zipping strings will convert the strings into lists. for example

```
print zip('foo','bar')
# will produce
[('f', 'b'), ('o', 'a'), ('o', 'r')]
```

What you want to do is simply

```
# in the beginning
address_book = []

# and in your loop
print { Name : Address }
address_book[ Name ] = Address
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this:

```
print "{",Name,":",Address,"}"
```

If you want to add all the inputs you receive into a single dictionary, do:

```
dictionary={}
for a in range(20):
    Name=raw_input()
    Address=raw_input()
    dictionary[Name]=Address
```

Comment: thanks aswin  @falstru mentioned the same solution as yours. Thanks again!!